# The database with a fully AES Encrypt Performance issue

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

My Customer want to encrypted everything with AES for protected the customer/invoice information! I made the .net application with Mysql database (host on Hostgator). Basically it works

My solution that on the startup of .net Application, we load all data (~ 12K rows)  decrypting and add to the cached list. And idea is from this list we process on ViewForm and when update data we encrypt data and update back to Mysql Database.

For about 5-10 rows it is working smoothly for processing, searching, and updating to the server, but after importing 12K data to database, then we got the issue, it took 5-7 hours for initials loading on startup and I must find the solution for that.

The code for Decrypt:

```
Using aesAlg As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        aesAlg.Key = Key
        aesAlg.IV = IV

        ' Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
        Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)

        Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream()
            Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                csDecrypt.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length)
                csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock()
                'Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)
                '    csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock()
                plaintext = msDecrypt.ToArray
                '    Return plaintext
                'End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

The code for Encrypt:

```
Using aesAlg As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        aesAlg.Key = Key
        aesAlg.IV = IV

        ' Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)

        ' Create the streams used for encryption.
        Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
            Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                csEncrypt.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length)
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock()
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    ' Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
    Return encrypted
```

I used for loading all to cached on startup (~ 40 properties x 12K rows)

```
list = (From p In Entities.Products.ToList() 
Select New Product With {.ProductID = p.ProductID,
  .PROPERTY = p.PROPERTY,
  .PROPERTY = Decrypt(p.PROPERTY),
  .PROPERTY = Decrypt(p.PROPERTY),
  .PROPERTY = Decrypt(p.PROPERTY),
  .PROPERTY = Decrypt(p.PROPERTY),
  .PROPERTY = Decrypt(p.PROPERTY),
  .PROPERTY = Decrypt(p.PROPERTY),
  .PROPERTY = Decrypt(p.PROPERTY),}
```

).ToList()

Somebody experienced with this issue, please give me the advice for the solution.

Comment: If you're encrypting all of the data like that, there is no point in a database.

Comment: The encryption itself should not have such an impact. Do you claim you have no such issue without encryption?

Comment: @gusto2 Yes we are fine with no encryption. The basic idea is we get 12K rows one time with Entity frameworks. On Select New Object With {row1 = DecryptFunction(row1), Row2, row3... row30}. All data on database are encrypted is requirement.

Comment: @Slaks: Yes, that requirements from the Customer! Because they store all sensitive inside.

Comment: Have you investigated the Tablespace/Transparent Encryption options built into MySQL?

Comment: @Alex: Basically yes!  But I dont have experience on Tablespace! Aes for mysql is using ECB mode and we are using CBC mode managed from .net function! But is the Tablespace can reslove my issue, it is easy for control from .net or Entiry framework?

Comment: Can you use AES-NI?

Comment: @kelalaka, seems it's hard to support on .net.

Comment: @Maarten, thanks for seems we're already implement the code with AES-IN. Here is the function for encrypt: 
`New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
            aesAlg.Key = Key
            aesAlg.IV = IV`

Comment: I added 2 function for encryption .